# Minimal Master Pages

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, libraries

I am currently using SP2010, I had a questions regarding master pages. If I set up a minimal master page as default, would I be able to use workflows, lists, libraries etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The master page determines the look and feel of your site. It does not change SharePoint's functionality to use lists and libraries, as long as the tools like ribbon etc. are still available.

Even if you omit the ribbon, you can use SharePoint Designer to create lists, libraries and workflows.

Comment: Thank you for that I appreciate it, it was weird to me because when I try to click on site permissions I get an error : 
  An unexpected error has occurred. Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

    Correlation ID: 8db156b6-0dad-4736-a064-e77e7687aad0

    Date and Time: 4/24/2015 9:43:40 PM

Comment: Check the logs for the error id to get a better idea what the error is about. Hard to say from a distance. If you cut down the master page and leave out elements that SharePoint needs, you will get errors, of course.